# How to copy branch with hierarchyid?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchyid

I have a simple table with fields:

```
catalog_id hierarchyid NOT NULL UNIQUE,
item_id int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
item_name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

[image]

I need to make a stored procedure which will copy branch to another parent.

for example, something like this:

[image]

I've done procedure for moving one branch from one parent to another, here it is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[move_child]
@ChildId int,
@NewParentId int
AS 
DECLARE @nold hierarchyid, @nnew hierarchyid
SELECT @nold = catalog_id FROM CatalogsTree WHERE item_id = @ChildId 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT @nnew = catalog_id FROM CatalogsTree WHERE item_id = @NewParentId

SELECT @nnew = @nnew.GetDescendant(max(catalog_id), NULL) 
FROM CatalogsTree WHERE catalog_id.GetAncestor(1)=@nnew ;

UPDATE CatalogsTree  
SET catalog_id = catalog_id.GetReparentedValue(@nold, @nnew)
WHERE catalog_id.IsDescendantOf(@nold) = 1 ;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

But now I need to make a copy with the same hierarchy and item_name.

Comment: Your table is screaming out for a `parentId` column. So `item_id: 11` should have the `parent_id: 9`. It will make life much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it with temporary table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[copy_child]
@folder_id int,
@new_parent_id int
AS
BEGIN
```

create temporary table:

```
create table #temp_table(
    catalog_id hierarchyid NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    item_id int NOT NULL,           
    item_name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

copy branch to temporary table:

```
declare @FolderId hierarchyid
select @FolderId = (select catalog_id from CatalogsTree where item_id = @folder_id)
INSERT INTO #temp_table (catalog_id, item_id, item_name)
SELECT catalog_id, item_id, item_name FROM CatalogsTree Where catalog_id.IsDescendantOf(@FolderId) = 1
```

change catalog_id:

```
DECLARE @nold hierarchyid, @nnew hierarchyid
SELECT @nold = catalog_id FROM CatalogsTree WHERE item_id = @folder_id

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT @nnew = catalog_id FROM CatalogsTree WHERE item_id = @new_parent_id

SELECT @nnew = @nnew.GetDescendant(max(catalog_id), NULL) 
FROM CatalogsTree WHERE catalog_id.GetAncestor(1) = @nnew ;

UPDATE #temp_table    
SET catalog_id = catalog_id.GetReparentedValue(@nold, @nnew)
WHERE catalog_id.IsDescendantOf(@nold) = 1 ;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

copy changed values to main table:

```
INSERT INTO CatalogsTree(catalog_id, item_name)
SELECT catalog_id, item_name FROM #temp_table

drop table #temp_table
END
```